# Jquery Datatables find range number in column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with five columns: A - B - C - D - E

Each column have an own filter.

A,B,C and E columns filters works fine. A,B,C have a simple input text search and E have a select type that search between two values.

The problem is D column.
D is a column of only numbers and the search rule is: find all values equal or major of search input.

How can I build that filter?

This is my example code:

```
  $('#reportstock thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#reportstock thead');
  $('#reportstock thead tr:eq(1) th.input').each(function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" class=\"form-control\" id="column_' + $(this).text() + '" placeholder=" cerca in ' + title.toLowerCase() + '" />');
                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("id") != "column_D") {
                        if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                            table.column(i)
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //??? find all values equal or major of search input.
                    }
            });
    });
```

Comment: [This example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) may give you some ideas on implementing a "_greater than or equal to_" filter. But if you have a variety of different filters which you want to use with different columns, then take a look at [Search Builder](https://datatables.net/blog/2020-09-01). Click on the "Add Condition" button to see it in action.

Comment: I have already tried with your first example, but the function
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push (...) starts every time table.draw () is launched;
Instead I would like that "greater than or equal to" filter works only when I enter a value in the column_D column
But your second example is already much more interesting!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 if ($(this).attr("id") != "column_D") {
    if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        table.column(i)
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    }
 }
 else {
      table.column(i).search() >= this.value ) {
      table.column(i)
         .search(this.value)
         .draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity who might have the same problem as me, I finally decided to solve this:

```
$('#reportstock thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#reportstock thead');
  $('#reportstock thead tr:eq(1) th.input').each(function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" class=\"form-control\" id="column_' + $(this).text() + '" placeholder=" cerca in ' + title.toLowerCase() + '" />');
                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("id") != "column_D") {
                        if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                            table.column(i)
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
    table.draw();
    }
            });
    });

    
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var min = parseInt($('#column_D').val(), 10);
                    var stock = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0;
                    if (isNaN(min) || (min <= stock))
                        return true;
    
                    return false;
                }
            );
```

It may not be the most elegant solution but it works!